# How to get rid of this npm message in terminal

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have this annoying message always showing whenever I do anything related to npm commond

`[..................] / : timing config:load:flatten`

How do I get rid of this ?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just the packages loading ?

Comment: No it's just stuck there forever @AbhishekMittal

Comment: What is system's configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by an old `.npmrc` file left in a workspace. deleting this file will resolve your error .

if not try to to update `node` and `npm` to the latest version